# PrestaShop: Change order of two fields in registration form

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I know this is not a Prestashop forum but I don't doubt that you have the solution I am looking for.
I want to change the order of two fields in the registration form in Prestashop 1.6. I also wanted to hide some unnecessary ones but that I have managed to do myself.

The field I want to move is the VAT field (moms in Swedish) as I have painted on the attached picture:

Because this field only is visible when the Company field is filled in I did not dare to touch it.

The field you can see on this image
[MOMS field should go before web address field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbLSs.png)

The code I think is to be changed come here

```
            <h3 class="page-subheading">{l s='Your company information'}    </h3>
            <p class="form-group">
                <label for="">{l s='Company'}</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company"     name="company" value="{if isset($smarty.post.company)}{$smarty.post.company}    {/if}" />
            </p>

            <p class="form-group">
                <label for="website">{l s='Website'}</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="website"     name="website" value="{if isset($smarty.post.website)}{$smarty.post.website}    {/if}" />
            </p>
        </div>
    {/if}
    {if isset($PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE) &&     $PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE}
        <div class="account_creation">
            <h3 class="page-subheading">{l s='Your address'}</h3>
            {foreach from=$dlv_all_fields item=field_name}
                {if $field_name eq "company"}
                    {if !$b2b_enable}
                        <p class="form-group">
                            <label for="company">{l s='Company'}{if     in_array($field_name, $required_fields)} <sup>*</sup>{/if}</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"     id="company" name="company" value="{if isset($smarty.post.company)}    {$smarty.post.company}{/if}" />
                        </p>
                    {/if}
                {elseif $field_name eq "vat_number"}
                    <div id="vat_number" style="display:none;">
                        <p class="form-group">
                            <label for="vat_number">{l s='VAT number'}{if     in_array($field_name, $required_fields)} <sup>*</sup>{/if}</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"     id="vat_number" name="vat_number" value="{if isset($smarty.post.vat_number)}    {$smarty.post.vat_number}{/if}" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                {elseif $field_name eq "firstname"}
                    <p class="required form-group">

                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control"     id="firstname" name="firstname" value="{if isset($smarty.post.firstname)}    {$smarty.post.firstname}{/if}" />
                    </p>
                {elseif $field_name eq "lastname"}
                    <p class="required form-group">

                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control"     id="lastname" name="lastname" value="{if isset($smarty.post.lastname)}    {$smarty.post.lastname}{/if}" />
                    </p>
```

Comment: My friend, this is very basic intervention, if you apply more I'm sure that you will find the solution.

Comment: I am too old for that I am afraid. So I still hope someone wants to answer even a basic question. Everyone is not skilled enough.

Comment: Aaaaww.. I'm sorry, I didn't want offend you. If is not urgent, I'll help you tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You have to move this field to the upper section:

```
            <h3 class="page-subheading">{l s='Your company information'}    </h3>
            <p class="form-group">
                <label for="">{l s='Company'}</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company"     name="company" value="{if isset($smarty.post.company)}{$smarty.post.company}    {/if}" />
            </p>

            <p class="form-group">
                <label for="website">{l s='Website'}</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="website"     name="website" value="{if isset($smarty.post.website)}{$smarty.post.website}    {/if}" />
            </p>
            {foreach from=$dlv_all_fields item=field_name}
                {if $field_name eq "vat_number"}
                    <div id="vat_number" style="display:none;">
                        <p class="form-group">
                            <label for="vat_number">{l s='VAT number'}{if     in_array($field_name, $required_fields)} <sup>*</sup>{/if}</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"     id="vat_number" name="vat_number" value="{if isset($smarty.post.vat_number)}    {$smarty.post.vat_number}{/if}" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
        </div>
    {/if}
    {if isset($PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE) &&     $PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE}
        <div class="account_creation">
            <h3 class="page-subheading">{l s='Your address'}</h3>
            {foreach from=$dlv_all_fields item=field_name}
                {if $field_name eq "company"}
                    {if !$b2b_enable}
                        <p class="form-group">
                            <label for="company">{l s='Company'}{if     in_array($field_name, $required_fields)} <sup>*</sup>{/if}</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"     id="company" name="company" value="{if isset($smarty.post.company)}    {$smarty.post.company}{/if}" />
                        </p>
                    {/if}                   
                {elseif $field_name eq "firstname"}
                    <p class="required form-group">

                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control"     id="firstname" name="firstname" value="{if isset($smarty.post.firstname)}    {$smarty.post.firstname}{/if}" />
                    </p>
                {elseif $field_name eq "lastname"}
                    <p class="required form-group">

                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control"     id="lastname" name="lastname" value="{if isset($smarty.post.lastname)}    {$smarty.post.lastname}{/if}" />
                    </p>
```